# Update Null values using values from other column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am new to using SQL queries on SQL Server, and hence I have met a roadblock.
I have a table in the given format

| CLASS_NAME | TYPE | DESCRIPTION |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | NULL | School |
| A | NULL | School |
| A | S | School |
| B | O | Office |
| B | NULL | Office |

However I want to replace the null values in TYPE column with matching values from CLASS_NAME and DESCRIPTION.
Example: When Class_Name = A and Description = School & TYPE IS NULL, then use the TYPE value where CLASS_NAME , TYPE & DESCRIPTION ARE NOT NULL (in this case TYPE = S).

Please feel free to ask for more demonstration if needed. Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: `update type=class_name where type is null and class_name='A' and description='School'`

Comment: `select distinct class_name, type, description where type is not null` will give you your options. Having verified that it contains no more than one line per a class_name+description pair (which is not necessarily the case), join that subquery to your table on class_name=class_name and description=description and type is null, and update type=type.

Comment: If the value of `type` in the second row in your table was, let's say, "T" instead of `null`, what is the rule for choosing whether the `null` in the first row should be "S" or "T"?

Comment: What happens if there are null values against `A` but also, let's say, `T` and `O` against `A`. What are you wanting to happen then?

Comment: @GSerg I'd really appreciate it if you could provide the whole query.

Comment: @allmhuran There will be only one TYPE value for distinct Class_Name and Description. Suppose, in our case for Class_Name = A, and Descritpion = School, there will only be TYPE = S. Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE yourTable SET 
    TYPE=U.[TYPE]
FROM (
SELECT DISTINCT T.[CLASS_NAME], T.[TYPE], T.[DESCRIPTION] 
FROM yourTable T
WHERE T.[TYPE] IS NOT NULL AND T.[DESCRIPTION] IS NOT NULL AND T.[CLASS_NAME] IS NOT NULL
) U 
WHERE 
    yourTable.[TYPE] IS NULL 
    AND U.[CLASS_NAME]=yourTable.[CLASS_NAME] 
    AND U.[DESCRIPTION]=yourTable.[DESCRIPTION]
```

But first check that your data is unambiguous:

```
SELECT [CLASS_NAME], [TYPE], [DESCRIPTION], COUNT(*)
FROM 
    yourTable
WHERE
    [CLASS_NAME] IS NOT NULL AND 
    [TYPE] IS NOT NULL AND
    [DESCRIPTION] IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY 
    [CLASS_NAME], 
    [TYPE], 
    [DESCRIPTION]
HAVING 
    COUNT(*) > 1
```

When above query returns any row - you have to replace ambiguous incorrect values and then run first query.

By "ambiguous" I mean the situation that there are more than one value of TYPE for the same CLASS_NAME and DESCRIPTION.

Comment: Thanks alot @DeuGe. This helped solve the problem! Cheers

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
    SELECT a.CLASS_NAME, a.DESCRIPTION, b.TYPE FROM TABLEA a 
    JOIN (SELECT CLASS_NAME, DESCRIPTION, TYPE from TABLEA where TYPE IS 
    NOTNULL) b on a.CLASS_NAME == b.CLASS_NAME and a.DESCRIPTION == 
    b.DESCRIPTION
```